# Is there a better word than "scene" when talking about books?

Tags: word-choice

From the dictionary it seems the word "scene" is appropriate for describing a part of a book:

> 2. a sequence of continuous action in a play, film, opera, or book.
>      "a scene from Tarantino's latest movie"

To me, it feels natural to use the word for plays, films and operas but it sounds strange to use it when referring to a book. Is there a better word or is "scene" indeed correct for books?

Comment: Chapter, segment, section, excerpt, selection, passage, portion, piece, extract, quotation, verse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say 'book', I assume you mean 'novel' rather than some kind of non-fiction.

Novels are traditionally divided into *chapters,* each containing one or more *scenes* and/or *passages*.

A scene would usually be considered to comprise (generally speaking) the description of a specific setting plus the action taking place in it. Because storytelling formats are so variable, that's about as far as I think one can safely go.

A passage need not encompass much in the way of action; it can be largely descriptive of a place, someone's appearance, or the back-story of a character (to pick a few possibilities more or less at random).

Answer (score 0):

here are some : section, segment, part, clip, sequence.

search oxford.

Comment: You have to be careful using Oxford's synonyms. A scene and sequence are very different in certain contexts, for example. Rarely are two words true synonyms, and never are five of them.

Comment: @Cody LaBarber: Wordnet has a usable definition of _synonymous_ <: Noun 1. synonym - two words that can be interchanged in a context are said to be synonymous relative to that context.> I can't think of **any** two words (except spelling variants) that are interchangeable in all contexts.

Answer (score -1):

You could probably use:
Section
part
chapter
or you could find the page number and use that, maybe the chapter if its a broader statement